# How to keep showing current page until next page data load completely and then show the next page without refreshing current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to keep showing current page until next page data load completely and then show the next page without refreshing current page? Also I would like to show slide up or down transition effect on page load.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Code?

Comment: I think you will need to use a SPA, framework,

Comment: You can use [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

Comment: maybe a promise with success ? or a simple `nextPageDataLoaded().then( load page ) `

Comment: Is it Single page application?

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, but i m not working on single page website. The idea is similar to single page website but i want to implement it on multi-page website.

Comment: Just like in single page website when ever we click a navigation menu another page slide up, I want to give same transition effect (slide up or slide down) on multi-page website when new page loads. The idea I came to think of is to stay on current page instead of showing loading screen then apply transition effect on new page load. I hope my idea is workable. Looking forward for your help guys. Thank you....

Comment: Even if there is any other way to make it workable, I m looking forward to it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `setTimeout()` function to keep current page for a specified amount of time and then load the next page after all the controls on the next page are loaded:

```
setTimeout(LoadLater, 7000); // Wait 7 seconds
function LoadLater(){
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in"; // enter next page url here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea Prachi, but it is not what i was looking for. May be i didn't explained clearly. :)  The idea is similar to single page website but i want to implement it on multi-page website. Just like in single page website when ever we click a navigation menu another page slide up, I want to give same transition effect (slide up or slide down) on multi-page website when new page loads. The idea I came to think of is to stay on current page instead of showing loading screen then apply transition effect on new page load. I hope my idea is workable. Looking forward for your help. Thanks